Permission denied when executing an rsync command using a third server to copy a file over to another server
I'm trying to copy files over from one server to another using a bastion server with rsync, so I have the list of origin servers and a list of target servers, the strange part is that when I use the bastion host to copy the file over to the second server I get the "Permission Denied" error. The command that I'm using to copy over the file is:
ssh originserver "rsync -azv --delete --partial /home/user/testing targetserver:/home/user/testing"

I then get prompted for the originserver and then again for the targetserver password, after I provide both passwords I get the error:
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.

Now, if I execute the same command in the originserver as:
rsync -azv --delete --partial /home/user/testing targetserver:/home/user/testing 

Unless I don't understand how executing a command remotely using the ssh command works but I thought it was the exact same as executing the command in the server after you log in via ssh, I don't understand why the difference.
As you can see in the second execution of the command I don't get any errors and the file gets copied over successfully, now, the problem is that if I need to ssh to every single server to execute the command to copy the file over to different servers, that will be very inefficient and would take a long time and of course prone to errors, my last goal is to build a script that can take the origin server and target servers from two files and make this very efficient, but this error is not letting me do that, any ideas?

First to mind is the environment, but not sure how permissions would fail. For curiosity, assuming user "testing", try  'ssh originserver "source /home/testing/.bash_profile && rsync -azv ...rest-of-cmds..."' ?
